# how to change margin between items in popupmenu

Tags: android, android-menu, popupmenu, android-popupwindow

I want to change the space between items in my popupmenu on android

the space i mean is this one:
[image]

I hope there is a straight foward solution, but as i know android it shall not be so simple

anyway i would like also to set the `maxHeight` of my popUp...
In this case popup is achored by the TextView "Select the prize" so it fills the space above it, but not all the items fit in that space so android automatically creates an scrow view (on vertical)

the thing is, I know 100% of users wont use this scroll so the items in my menu bellow "Travel" will never be seen.

How can i set the height in order to make enough space to all items?

=============UPDATE================

Just to make it clear, this isn't a spinner it is a popupmenu

```
this.popupCategories = new PopupMenu(this, this.categoryLabel);
for (Giveaway.GiveawayCategoryGroup catGroup : categoryGroups) {

            SubMenu submenu = this.popupCategories.getMenu().addSubMenu(catGroup.getDescription(lang));
            for (Giveaway.GiveawayCategory cat : (Collection<? extends Giveaway.GiveawayCategory>) catGroup.getCategories()) {
                if (cat.isActive())
                    submenu.add(Menu.NONE, cat.getValue().hashCode(), (int) cat.getOrder(), cat.getDescription(lang));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set your preferred item row height in your AppTheme inside `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">20dp</item>
</style>
```

You may need to modify this number a bit to get the correct value, but it determines the height of those rows. Make sure to replace `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` with whatever you're currently using.

As for setting a maximum height, I'm afraid you'll have to create your own extension class for that, as [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22002054/608312).

Comment: one extra question: when deal with those standard android styles... how can i know which one to override without trying a lots of them? ( i knew there was a styles for that but couldn't figure out which)

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is googling it or looking on Stack overflow. The answers can be found in the documentation, but it's usually pretty hard to find yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`PopupMenu` items are just regular `MenuItem`; it's the same attribute, but another parent style:

```
<style name="customPopupMenuStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">32dp</item>
</style>
```

this only affects the `PopupMenu` to which the style had been assigned to.

also there one could set a custom `ActionView` (per individual item, not as a template):

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.itemMenu);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.layout_menu);
```

Comment: this isn't a spinner... i added the code to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

You can create a layout for popup menu and initialize it in your activity as follows
**XML**

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:background="@android:color/transparent">
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="YOUR MAX HEIGHT"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:weightsum="YOUR NUMBER OF ITEMS"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         >
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="0dp"
>             android:weight="1" /> ...no of views items
>     </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

INITIALIZE IT AS

```
View parentv = findViewById(R.id.activityview); //id of parent view of activity in which popup will be shown
LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURPOPUPMENU, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        TextView tv = popupView.findViewById(R.id.textviewid); //to do something with textview
        tv.setText("Fashion");
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true); //if you want to dismiss popup if clicked outside
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        // Removes default background.
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
//        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.righttoleftstyle); can put animation to slide in popupmenu by defining any animation
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(parentv, Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP,0,0);
```

//will show popup on top left corner of the screen of the activity view you can try some iterations for it to show where on screen according to your needs

I hope it will help!